# New Twilio Voice Recognition (Force alphanumeric, "non-word" input?)

Tags: twilio, voice-recognition

I am looking to build an application that gets inventory information for products based on the caller's specific product request. All of these products are alphanumeric, and don't use any words, which is part of the problem.

During a test call, I requested "**DBN5009K**"

In the logs, you can see that it interpreted it as below:

```
SpeechResult    BBN 5009 okay
```

I'm not looking for a perfect result, and planned to scrub the input of whitespace and then run a Levenshtein algorithm to match the closest item. If the result had been **B**BN5009**K**, I'm confident that I'd be able to match it to **D**BN5009K, without much trouble. (It would have a Levenshtein distance of 1.) **B**BN5009**okay** will probably never match properly, with a distance of 5 on a string that is only 11 characters long.

Can Twilio be forced to not use "words"? Can it be trained with a specific dataset of appropriate options? They use not having to train as a marketing plus, which it almost always is, but in this case that's a problem. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Seth

Comment: If you tell me DBN over the phone I (as human) might understand BBN. Then, how you expect a machine not to make mistakes in parsing the audio. If you're to input data over voice your "DBN5009K" should be "Delta Bravo November 5 0 0 9 Kilo".

Comment: I fully agree. The D and B swap isn't my issue, though. It's the K getting swapped for "okay." I can handle the first problem, but not the second. That's why I'm looking to find a way to limit Twilio's response engine to simply letters and numbers. A call sign type method may work better, but these are unsophisticated users who would just hit 0 for the Operator if they had to come up with words for each letter, or enter the item number using a phone key pad. Thanks.

Comment: There many speech APIs around which allow either hints or more flexible language specification, not sure why are you bounded to Twilio, it would be very hard to make it recognize complex sequences accurately.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? Google's API is limited to 500 "hints", and I'd need a few thousand. (That sounds like a lot, but it's only about 20KB in size. Twilio was the logical jumping off point as everything is tied into one platform, with less moving parts outside of their environment. Otherwise, I need to use a telephone API, record the clip, transfer that clip to a different service, then go back to the voice client with the results. I'm hopeful to find something, but not expecting it at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio's speech recognition](https://www.twilio.com/speech-recognition) is good for parsing general speech as that's what it's trained for. It's not so good for parsing specific things, as you've found out.

Within the Twilio platform, you'll want to be able to train the engine to recognise your product IDs. This is [natural language understanding](https://www.twilio.com/understand) that is coming soon.

In the meantime, you may want to use [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) and a recognition engine that you can train yourself. Also, [sign up to get updates on Understand](https://www.twilio.com/understand).

Comment: Thank you, much. That's what I thought. I look forward to the new feature. I was excited when voice recognition was announced, so I can wait a little longer, I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can programmatically handle it by replacing the substring 'okay' of the SpeechResult by 'k' if SpeechResult contains 'okay'.

Comment: It's a bad solution.